# Default values of a prop of type object in vue are not being used

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm not sure why the default values of a prop, in object format, in vue are not being accepted but when I pass in the props dynamically the values appear fine.

I have a component, `component1`, it has:

```
<label :style="setTextStyles"></label>

props: {
    textStyles: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({
        'textColor': 'white',
        'uppercase': 'uppercase',
        'fontWeight': 'bold',
      })
    }
},
computed:{
    setTextStyles() {
      return {
        'font-weight': this.textStyles.fontWeight,
        'text-transform': this.textStyles.uppercase,
        '--color': this.textStyles.textColor
      }
}
```

I have a second component that uses component 1:

```
<component1 :textStyles="{'textColor':'red', 'uppercase':'None','fontWeight':'bold'}"/>
```

Which ever prop I specify, ie textColor, or upprecase or fontWeight, I see the expected result. However the default values don't seem to show up if I don't specify it. For example, the fontWeight is not bold by default even though it's set as the default font weight. This is the same with textColor.

Below does not give me a bold font:

```
<component1 :textStyles="{'textColor':'red', 'uppercase':'None'}"/>
```

Below does not give me a white text color:

```
<component1 :textStyles="{'uppercase':'None','fontWeight':'bold'}"/>
```

I'm not sure why the default values are not appearing

Comment: There is only one default value for the object. So if you assign another object to it don't expect the unassigned properties remain the same.

Comment: I see, what would be the best way to go about this? I decided to use an object because I thought I could group them all together instead of creating multiple props

Comment: You can have them both. A complex property for bulk assignment and separated properties for each. And then you watch the complex property and assign each property when set

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Do not expect vue props to act like function arguments in javascript. Instead you can have the default values in a separate variable inside the component and use `Object.assign()` to build the final desired object.

For example:

```
const defaultStyles = {
        'textColor': 'white',
        'uppercase': 'uppercase',
        'fontWeight': 'bold',
      }

export default {
  props : {
    textStyles : { 
       default : {},
       type : Object
    }
  }, 
  
  data(){
    return {
       finalStyles : Object.assign({}, defaultStyles, textStyles)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a composable like this.
This way you can also use `vue-router` props without loosing your defaults.

```
<script>
/**
   * This composable is merging default Properties against a given property
   * usage:
   * setup(props) {
    const defaultedProperty = useMergePropertyDefaults(
      {
        teleportBottom: true,
        showErrors: true,
        showLoadingAnimation: true,
        showPublishedWarning: true,
      },
      toRef(props, "renderControl")
    );

    return { defaultedProperty };
  },
  props: {
    renderControl: {
      type: Object,
      required: false,
    },
  },
   **/
import { computed } from "vue";

export default function useMergePropertyDefaults(
  defaultProperties,
  propertyRef
) {
  const processed = computed(() => {
    const values = {
      ...defaultProperties,
      ...propertyRef.value,
    };
    return values;
  });

  return processed;
}
</script>
```